# How to extend a module on a class dynamically?

Tags: ruby

I currently have two classes with each extending a different module:

```
class Example1
  def initialize
    extend TopModule:SubModule1
  end
end

class Example2
  def initialize
    extend TopModule:SubModule2
  end
end
```

Instead of having two classes with each its own module extended, is it possible to create a single class and then extend the module at the object level?

I have added the name of the module and passing that to the constructor of the object but complains with the code.

```
class Example
  def initialize (module)
    self.send("extend TopModule::#{module}"
  end
end

object = Example.new('Submodule1')

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `extend TopModule::SubModule1' for #<Example:0x00000000057c8198>
```

Overall problem: Let's say I have N objects (they all should come from the same class BUT each object must have it's own module). What would be the best approach to have this capability?

Comment: Are the classes extending the modules or are individual instances of your class extending the module?

Comment: Individual instance of the class should extend the module

Comment: Given your "Overall problem" I would say you should have N classes and 1 module that contains the common logic rather than 1 class that contains the common logic and N modules to distinguish them dynamically at run time

Comment: Calling `extend` during `initialize` is kind of an odd thing to do. Normally you'd just `include` in the class itself once and once only.

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to do this. You are left with a collection of instances of `Example`, some of which respond to the instance methods in `Submodule1`; others than that respond to the instance methods of `Submodule2`. You obviously have to keep track of which group each instance is in. I would think the simplest way of doing that is to simply create subclasses of `Example`: `class Ex1 < Example; include Submodue1`; end; class Ex2 < Example; include Submodule2; end`.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer!

```
module TopModule
  module SubModule1
    def hello
      puts "Hello from #1"
    end
  end
end

module TopModule
  module SubModule2
    def hello
      puts "Hello from #2"
    end
  end
end

class Example
  def initialize(mod)
    extend TopModule.const_get(mod)
  end
end

Example.new("SubModule1").hello
# => Hello from #1
Example.new("SubModule2").hello
# => Hello from #2
```

Comment: You might wish to change the `extend` argument to `Kernel.const_get("TopModule::#{mod}")` to fit the requirements a bit more.

Comment: ^^ Thanks, Marcin. Updated and scoped from TopModule.

Comment: Is the `self.` necessary?

Comment: ^^ Updated Kimmo

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly on wrong way, and that forces you to find an "ungood" solution. [But here it is.](https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/StarryBiodegradablePortablesoftware)

```
class Example
  def initialize m
    self.instance_eval("extend Topmodule::#{m}")
  end
end
```

Comment: `eval` technically works here, but it's kind of overkill for what is a simple dynamic programming problem.

Comment: Please don't link to code. If the link is broken in future your answer is kaput. btw, you don't need `self.`.